# Problem with deleting from CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using this code for deleting an entry from CoreData:

```
        NSManagedObjectContext *context2=[self managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *fetch2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity2=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RecentMovies" inManagedObjectContext:context2];
        [fetch2 setEntity:entity2];
        [fetch2 setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
        NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"DateTime"];
        NSExpression *minDateExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"min:"
                                                    arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
        NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
        [expressionDescription setName:@"minDateTime"];
        [expressionDescription setExpression:minDateExpression];
        [expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDateAttributeType];    
        [fetch2 setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];

        error=nil;
        NSArray *objects2 = [context2 executeFetchRequest:fetch2 error:&error];
        if (objects2 == nil) {
            // Handle the error.
            NSLog(@"ERRORS IN SEARCH INSIDE VIEW SUCCESS");
        }
        else {
            if ([objects2 count] > 0) {
                NSLog(@"Minimum date: %@", [[objects2 objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"minDateTime"]);

                //delete the oldest entry !
                for (NSManagedObject *object2 in objects2) {
                    [context2 deleteObject:object2];
                }

            }
        }
```

However, I am getting the following error :

```
Minimum date: 2011-08-03 08:32:35 +0000
2011-08-03 03:33:15.014 EncameoApp[1933:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts.'
```

Any help ?

I also have 2 other tables in CoreData and the [self managedObjectContext] is shared between all the CoreData code. I am a little confused here about the error message regarding the context ...

Answer (score 0):

It usually a bad idea to alter the Array you are iterating on.

```
                for (NSManagedObject *object2 in objects2) {
                [context2 deleteObject:object2];
            }
```

Comment: Not sure what you meant, I am not altering the Array, 1 of them is object2 and the other is objects2 ...they are not the same name...   ... :-s

Comment: object2 is an object in objects2, you then proceed to delete object2 and thereby changing objects2 array. The problem then arises in the loop as a object2 is taken out and another object2 takes its place in the array, changing the [objects count] value that the fast enumerator uses.

Comment: I don't think the count of objects2 is affected by deleting object2 from the managed object context. I suggest setting a breakpoint on objc_exception_throw to debug your situation.